# Let $a^n$ be an integer number for some $n$ such that $a$ a rational number. Why $a$ must be integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a^n$ be an integer number for some $n$ such that $a$ a rational number. Why $a$ must be integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may assume that $a=\frac{c}{d}$, where $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime. Let $a^n=k$. Then $c^n=kd^n$.

If $d\ne 1$, then some prime $p$ divides $d$. Then $p$ divides $c^n$, and therefore $p$ divides $c$. This contradicts the fact that $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime. Thus $d=1$, and therefore $a$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint(s):

1. Think rational root theorem applied to $T^n-a^n$
2. If $b^n\mid a^n$, does it follows that $b\mid a$? Think about the primes involved.

Answer (score 0):

Let a/b be your Rational number . Use the prime number decomposition of each of a,b:

$a= p_1^{e_1}...p_k^{e^k}$ ;

$b= P_1^{d_1}...P_m^{d^m}$

Where each of the $p_i$ and $P_j$ are prime, and each of the $e_i, d_j$ are positive integers.

Then $\frac {a^n}{b^n}= \frac {p_1^{ne_1} p_2^{ne_2}....p_k^{ne_k}}{P_1^{nd_1}....P_m^{ne_m}}$

Then every factor in the denominator must cancel out. But the $P_j$'s are all prime, so they cannot factor as $P_i=p_j p_k$ . It follows that each $P_i$ equals some $p_k$.